# Interpreting of Omitted subject and verb

Tags: omissibility, conversational-deletion

> When you have a moment, could you please send over next Wednesday’s campaign info? 
>   Double-checking a couple details before it goes live to make sure the client is happy!

The above sentences are from an e-mail. In the last sentence, I know what the author want to say. But, I wonder how it would be read to general readers.

(a) I want to double-check ...

(b) Double-checking a couple details before it goes ***makes*** sure that ...

(c) ***It is for*** double-checking ....

Or if something was omitted, what would be omitted?

Comment: Choice (A) looks right.  The others?  Welcome to the world of commerce, where illiteracy reigns supreme.

Comment: I would interpret this as "I'm double checking..."

Comment: 'Just double-checking ...' sounds far more idiomatic to me. Then (a) is virtually inescapable.

Comment: Thank you all. May I assume always that "~ing + objective" can be interpreted as "I want to ~(verb) + objective" ?

Comment: ... That is very far from the true situation. 'I want to leave the station' and '[I'm] Just leaving the station' are miles apart. And as for 'I want to marry Beyonce' ...  'Just checking' is a rather unusual example; '[I] Just want to check' / 'Just checking' are really hedged forms of 'I'm going to check' [whether you like it or not].

Comment: The final quote should have come after the implied parenthetical addition.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a typical case of ommitted subject (I) and auxiliary verb (to be), since the continous form implies them both, giving you the general meaning of your proposal A. From context, it also looks like they're providing you with their individual motivation for asking for this information.

In that case, your proposals B and C are not correct since the "un-personification" of the phrase is not in line with the overall context of your situation. Those two phrases would be coherent with context if the person was talking about procedures or processes.

Without omission, it would look like:
When you have a moment, could you please send over next Wednesday's campaign info? I'm double-checking a couple of details before it goes live to make sure the client is happy.